# Angular 10 ngb-progress bar not displaying

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I have an Angular 10 project using the Bootstrap ngb-progressbar. I have written a service that I can use throughout my app to show and hide the progress bar as needed. It displays during the initial application load, but not any other time I invoke it.

Everything compiles and runs fine and no errors are seen in the console. I have tried to show all relevant code.

**progress-bar.component.html**

Note: if I remove the *ngIf="loading" from here the progress bar shows on every page. So I think my bootstrap stuff is all ok.

```
<div id="content-loading" class="overlay" *ngIf="loading">
    <div class="progress">
        <ngb-progressbar value="1000" style="width: 100%">Loading</ngb-progressbar>
    </div>
</div>
```

**progress-bar.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbProgressbarConfig } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ProgressBarService } from './progress-bar.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'ngbd-progressbar',
    templateUrl: './progress-bar.component.html',
    providers: [NgbProgressbarConfig],
    //moduleId: module.id
})

export class ProgressBarComponent  {
    public loading: boolean;

    constructor(config: NgbProgressbarConfig, progressBar: ProgressBarService) {
        config.max = 1000;
        config.striped = true;
        config.animated = true;
        config.type = 'primary';

        progressBar.status.subscribe((status: boolean) => {
            this.loading = status;
        });
    }
}
```

**progress-bar.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ProgressBarService {
    private _loading: boolean = false;

    public status: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

    constructor() {

    }

    public get loading(): boolean {
        return this._loading;
    }

    public set loading(v: boolean) {
        this._loading = v;
        this.status.next(v);
    }

    public start(): void {
        this.loading = true;
    }

    public stop(): void {
        this.loading = false;
    }
}
```

It is exported from a shared component

**shared.component.ts**

```
export * from './progress-bar/progress-bar.component';
```

**shared.service.ts**

```
export * from './progress-bar/progress-bar.service';
```

And imported into the app.module

**app.module**

```
import { ProgressBarComponent } from './shared/shared.component';
import { ProgressBarService } from './shared/shared.service';
...
declarations: [
ProgressBarComponent,
]
providers: [
ProgressBarService,
]
```

And put in the app component html

**app.component.html**

```
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <breadcrumb></breadcrumb>
                        <ngbd-progressbar></ngbd-progressbar> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

As for usage in a component it involves the use of a base-component

**base.component.ts**

```
import { ProgressBarService } from '../progress-bar/progress-bar.service';
...
export class BaseComponent {
    protected _progressBarService: ProgressBarService;

    constructor(
        progressBarService: ProgressBarService,
        toastr: ToastrService) {
            
            this._progressBarService = progressBarService;
            this._toastr = toastr;
         }


}
```

And then usage in a component is as follows. Behavior is just no progress bar overlay is ever seen.

**case-index.component.ts**

```
import { BaseComponent } from '../../shared/ui/base.component';
import { ProgressBarService } from '../../shared/progress-bar/progress-bar.service';
...
export class CaseIndexComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(
      progressBarService: ProgressBarService,
) { super(progressBarService, toastr); }
...
search(e: any): void {
this._progressBarService.start();
      this._caseService.getByCriteria(criteria)
          .subscribe(c => this.searchSuccess(c),
              error => this.displayError(error));
}
...
searchSuccess(cases: Case[]): void {
      this.cases = cases;
      this._progressBarService.stop();

      if (this.cases.length == 0) {
          this._toastr.info('No Search Results');
      }
  }
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: This is waay to much code. Please narrow it down. Try removing code and demonstrating the problem in a JSFiddle or so.

Comment: I don't see an imported module for the progress bar in your app module. Without it, it will just be handled as 'normal' html.

Comment: Sorry for the amount of code. It's not an easy thing to demonstrate. And yes, I do have the ProgressBarComponent in the app.module declarations. I'll edit my question.

Comment: add some log in `progressBar.status.subscribe((status: boolean) => { console.log('status fired', status); ....` from progress-bar.component.ts and valid it

Comment: interesting results jd_7. I can see the "status fired true" and "status fired false" when routing to a page. However no messages on the long running process.

Comment: It's like it works on any component that is imported directly in app.module, but if I have a sub module that is lazy loaded in the  app-routing.module it is not working.

Comment: add `ProgressBarService` to module where is `case-index.component.ts` as `providers` too.

Comment: You need to import that component in every module where you're using it. If you have multiple components that you want to use in multiple modules you can create a module that only exports those components and then import that module in every module where you want to use them.

Comment: I believe I do have that. shared.component.ts exports progress-bar.component, and then that is imported into app.module.ts. I can't then import it into the case.module as well or it is in more then 1 module.